# Create Web Host builder error when compiling mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Whenever I try to run my MVC project in VS 2019 i am getting a Exception Unhanded error (Image is below). I have tried to create a new project and that works fine. I did not make any changes, the project ran fine and then I stopped it and re ran it and I got this error.

Error Image here

[image: Error Image here]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VS is run as administrator, and your account has access to the file `hostsettings.json`.